# Splunk Otel Collector Multiline Config

Tags: logging, kubernetes-helm, splunk, otel

We have a problem with the multiline config of splunk-otel-collector. I tested our regex to find stacktraces with regex101 and it works just fine there. However, our logs are still being splitted into several logs. I can think of an problem with the wildcards we have set for namespaces, pods and containers. Anyone has an idea what I can look into to resolve this?

Goal: Don't split logs that start with leading whitespace nor "Caused by"

```
    multilineConfigs: 
      - namespaceName:
          value: .*
        podName:
          value: .*
          useRegexp: true
        containerName:
          value: .*
        firstEntryRegex: ^(?:\s|Caused by)
```